# where is a page protected variable is saved?

Tags: asp.net

I have added a protected var to my page as below :

```
public partial class .... : ....
{
    protected string Lang;
    ...
}
```

I save requested language into it . to access it in design mode for example in a  tag

```
<a href='<%= string.Format("/{0}/sample.aspx",Lang) %>' > Click me </a>
```

I want to know where is this variable's value saved . in viewstate ? or ...

Comment: Sorry if I ask, is your question "If a user selects a language, where can I save it so that the language will be used from now on for every link/request" ?

Comment: You have your answer in the below link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609771/asp-net-protected-variable

Comment: @Luke no , I just want to know when I set a value in this variable is it's value saved in somewhere or is deleted after render of page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value is not saved at all, any more than private fields or properties are stored. They exist only while the page instance exists.

Comment: Exactly. The pipline looks like this. Request comes => Corresponding instance of IHttpHandler (in this case `Page`) is created => Prefilled if there is a ViewState => Methods executed => Html generated => Html flushed to client => Created page object destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

You can create property `public string Lang{get;set}` instead of your field
And then use this `<%#Eval("Lang")%>`  to get value from property